# How to trigger woocommerce callback function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to test that my callback function works by visiting the callback URL in my browser http://localhost:90/wordpress-payment-demo/wc-api/callback_handler/ but I keep getting -1. Here is my callback function.

```
$this->id = 'paymentplugin';

add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_' . $this->id , array( $this, 'callback_handler' ) );

function callback_handler() { 
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
    echo "callback";
    die();
}
```

I also tried posting to the URL with Postman and I get a status code of 400 bad request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like a webhook for a custom WooCommerce payment gateway. In this case you probably don't need the `_wc_` in the `add_action` function.

Example:

```
$this->id = 'paymentplugin';

add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . $this->id , array( $this, 'webhook' ) );

function webhook() { 
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
    echo "callback";
    die();
}
```

You also **need not to end execution**, because this is done by WooCommerce, hence you will probably want to remove the `die()` function:

```
$this->id = 'paymentplugin';

add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . $this->id , array( $this, 'webhook' ) );

function webhook() { 
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );
    echo "callback";
}
```

Another thing to consider are **headers**. I don't know if they need to be sent but I recently created a custom gateway which only has this code in the webhook and it works perfectly:

```
function webhook() {
  $order_id = isset($_GET['order_id']) ? $_GET['order_id'] : null;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order->payment_complete();
  wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
}
```

The payment provider basically sends an IPN containing the order ID which I previously sent, so I can confirm that the order was paid.

Here is a link to the custom gateway I recently created, hopefully it can help:

https://github.com/usainicola/weldpay-woocommerce

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked the webhook/callback function seems to always return -1. However, it runs successfully. The other issue was that I was using the wrong URL it shouldn't be the name of the function but the id "**paymentplugin**" in this example.

Comment: @nicola if I don't put the die() it returns -1 for some reason. If I put it, it works correctly and echoes a string. Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have followed your example in your github, and it works! FWIW, For those who may get http error 404, you can check your api url. In my case "/wc-api/callback/" didn't work because it turned out that my wordpress settings used plain permalink, so it should be "?wc-api=callback" instead.