# Woocommerce Api callback don't running and return -1 value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am creating a payment plugin for woocommerce and I must receive a response from the payment gateway as a callback. When I test the callback url, I receive -1 as value with 200 as status code.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_api_'.$this->id, array($this,'ocCallback') );`

```
public function ocCallback(){
            echo'ok';
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what would be the expected return code?

Comment: according to my code, I just made an echo of "ok"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your own output, place die() before end in your function, this works for me.
And header() in first line, like the sample in this question

[How to trigger woocommerce callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057758/how-to-trigger-woocommerce-callback-function)

Note comment #2 after the accepted answer.

-1 is returned either when called URL is wrong, but with HTTP/400 code instead of HTTP/200.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now.